builders won't affect table in flutter_markdown
GreenTableBuilder:
class GreenTableBuilder extends MarkdownElementBuilder {
  @override
  Widget? visitElementAfterWithContext(BuildContext context, md.Element element, TextStyle? preferredStyle, TextStyle? parentStyle) {
    if (element.tag == 'table') {
      final rows = <TableRow>[];

      for (final tableChild in element.children ?? []) {
        if (tableChild.tag == 'tr') {
          rows.add(_buildTableRow(tableChild));
        } else {
          for (final row in tableChild.children ?? []) {
            if (row.tag == 'tr') {
              rows.add(_buildTableRow(row));
            }
          }
        }
      }
      print("return table");
      return DecoratedBox(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green),
        child: Table(
          border: TableBorder.all(),
          children: rows,
        ),
      );
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget? visitText(md.Text text, TextStyle? preferredStyle) {
    return const Text("text.text");
  }

  TableRow _buildTableRow(md.Element rowElement) {
    final cells = <Widget>[];

    for (final cell in rowElement.children ?? []) {
      cells.add(
        Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: const Text("cell.textContent"),
        ),
      );
    }
    return TableRow(children: cells);
  }
}

MarkdownBody:
MarkdownBody(
                  data: '''
|h1|h2|h1|h2|h1|h2|
|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|
|`row1`|[row2](https://google.com)|row1|row2|row1|row2|
|row1|row2|row1|row2|row1|row2|
|row1|row2|row1|row2|row1|row2|
|row1|row2|row1|row2|row1|row2|
|row1|row2|row1|row2|row1|row2|
|row1|row2|row1|row2|row1|row2|
''',
                  onTapLink: (text, href, title) {
                    print("onTapLink, text:$text, href:$href, title:$title");
                  },
                  builders: {
                    'table': GreenTableBuilder(),
                  },
                ),
        )

I want to write a builder for table to custom table header & body,
But it seems to do nothing despite visitElementAfterWithContext() has been run through(printed "return table" in debug console).
The table is neither wrapped in a container widget with a green background nor is the text changed to "text.text" or "cell.textContent".
Is there something I missing?
